# HTML form data to PHP script

Tags: php, html, file, parsing, upload

What small background I have is in Python. I've never used PHP before, so I'm somewhat lost. What I'm trying to do is upload files through an HTML form and then parse the files with a PHP script and display the results back to the user.

This is my HTML:

```
<html>    
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='read.php'
    method='POST'>
<input type='hidden'/>
Choose a file to upload: <input name='uploadedfile' type='file' multiple /><br />
<input type='submit' value='Upload File' />
</form>

</html>
```

it seems to work, but I could be missing something obvious.

My PHP script is

```php
<?php
if ($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'] !==false)
    file_get_contents($_FILES);
    foreach (glob($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]) as $file) {
        if (is_uploaded_file($file['temp_name']))
        $file_handle = fopen(file, "r");
        while (feof($file_handle)) {
        $e = array("code", "money", "notes", "date2");
        $n = 0;
        $line = fgets($file_handle);}
        foreach($line as $value) {
            if ($n=0);
                if (strpos($line, 'Sent:') !==false);{
                    array_push($e, $line);}
                if (strpos($line, 'REFERENCE NUMBER:') !==false) ;{
                    $n = 1;
                    array_push($e, $line);}
                if ($n<40);{
                        array_push($e, $line);
                        $n = $n+1;}
                echo $e;}}
?>
```

It doesn't do anything, and I'm not even sure whether the files are going through or if I just don't know how to access them. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *"it seems to work"*  and *"It doesn't do anything"* is contradictory. Use error reporting and tell us what errors you may be getting. You may want to have a second look at `fopen(file`. Error reporting should be throwing you a "Undefined constant file..." notice. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Apologies. I meant that the HTML seems to work (in that I get no errors when I try to upload files). The PHP script is what doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to upload multiple files, you need to set name of input as array:

```
<input name='uploadedfile[]' type='file' multiple />
```

And then you can read all uploaded files in cycle:

```
<?php
foreach ($_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'] as $i => $error) {
  if ($error === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $file_handle = fopen($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'][$i], 'r');

    // your code here

  } else {
    // check error number: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php
  }
}
```